# Change the input value not working with me [Not working]

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs, trying to change value of an input but not working so far

I got this error, however, i tried to change the website for testing!

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("1st-ib").setAttribute')
```

the command line for executing is

```
phantomjs.exe google.js "https://www.google.com.eg" "google"
```

My JS code is

```js
var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;
var system = require("system");

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

phantom.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.1.2987.98 Safari/537.36";

var steps = [
  function() {
    //Load Login Page
    page.open(system.args[1],function (status){
 page.evaluate(function(){
  //document.getElementById('lst-ib').value='text to be displayed' ;
  document.getElementById("1st-ib").setAttribute('value','My default value');
 }
 );
  }
  );
  }, 
  function() {
  page.render(system.args[2]+".png");
  }, 
  function() {

  }
];


interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
    console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 50);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is the page loaded when you are trying to execute - document.getElementById("1st-ib")?

Comment: Yea the page load but the input value not changed

Comment: Can you log out element? Make sure it's not null...

Comment: The textbox is Null and i want to set value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code line that works on change the value should be in other function because that needs time to load the page to find the input.

```
var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;
var system = require("system");

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

page.settings.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.1.2987.98 Safari/537.36";

var steps = [
  function() {
    //Load Login Page
    page.open(system.args[1],function (status){
  }
  );
  },
  function(){
        page.evaluate(function(){
        //document.getElementById('lst-ib').value='text to be displayed' ;
        document.getElementById("1st-ib").setAttribute('value','My default value');
    }
    );
},  
  function() {
        page.render(system.args[2]+".png");
  }, 
  function() {

  }
];


interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
    console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 50);
```